# Do you know me?

Tags: visual, movies

This is a character from a movie. If you want to know who I am 
look at the picture down and try to find a solution for this puzzle:

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> Thanos.

Because

> An alien + glove for left hand + collecting stones + of different colors.

Comment: Could you add spoiler tags, please? :)

Comment: @infinitezero Someone beat me to it, but I'll remember for next time!